# Unable to deploy an Ionic Framework app on ios device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic framework app with Ionic 2.  I can deploy via my MAC to an android device using 'ionic cordova run android'.  But when I execute 'ionic cordova run ios' I get the following error:

```
Code Signing Error: Signing for "App" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'
```

All of the online answers for this issue only mention signing provisions in xCode but I'm not sure how that would resolve an Ionic app created in Visual Code.  I didn't do any development in xCode and it's only installed in order to use the emulator.  The solutions say to open the app in xcode for the signing but you can't even open an Ionic app in xCode.

Could someone please help with this, I've had this issue for weeks with ios.

Answer (score 2):

Open the .xcodeproj in xcode, go to the **project settings**, and under **signing**, use the **team** dropdown menu to select a dev team and remove the error. This error is occurring because to emulate an ios app, it has to be built using xcode.

Comment: The .xcodeproj file is located in your {project}/platforms/ios folder